# Postwoman API Tester response is always empty

Tags: api, hoppscotch

[Postwoman](https://postwoman.io/) (now [Hoppscotch](https://hoppscotch.io/)) is an API request builder (like Postman) that I love the idea of because it's open source, but I'm not getting any response showing up in the Response field. It's a private API I'm hitting so I'd rather not show my request but it's a POST and my API is sending back the correct response (that works fine in Postman). I'm seeing the following error in the browser console:

`TypeError: text.match is not a function`

Is anybody else having this problem?

Comment: Postman and Postwoman are different, do not use Postman tag along with it! For further help, you can contact with it's creator.

Answer (score 0):

Adding browser extension:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hoppscotch/
done the trick for me